# What is the distribution of the conditional probability $(N(a)|N(b) =c )$ of a poisson process $N(t)\geq t$ if $a>b$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process

I know that if $a<b$ then the conditional probability is $BIN(n, a/b)$ but what happens if $a>b$?

Comment: It is a poisson process evaluated at $a-b$ shifted up by $c$.  (Let $M$ be an identical poisson process, then $N(a)$ has the same distribution as $M(a-b) + c$.)